# How to choose specific id from the array

Tags: php, css

How can I apply CSS underline to the following $name results where id=34,40 without using SQL query. Please help.

```
foreach($index[$parent_id] as $id) {
  $name=$data[$id]["name"];
  echo str_repeat('&nbsp', $level) . "$name.$id  <br>";
}
```

Comment: You have a learning curve ahead. start with basics.

Comment: entities have to be terminated with `;` so it should be `&nbsp;` not `&nbsp`. Also do not abuse tags. Your question is not CSS related.

Answer (score 0):

Php is great at creating HTML and HTML can reference CSS without a thought.

If you have a CSS class called underline...

```
.underline {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

...then all you need to do is wrap your output in a tag like this:

```
echo  '<div class="underline">'.$name.$id.'</div>';
```

That said I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with the str_repeat function, so you'd need to mod this to work with that.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply a span around your output

```
echo str_repeat('&nbsp', $level) . "<span class="underline">$name.$id  </span><br>";
```

and then style the class

```
.underline{text-decoration:underline;}
```

OR...

you can directly style it

```
echo str_repeat('&nbsp', $level) . "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">$name.$id  </span><br>";
```

hope this helps

Comment: entities have to be terminated with ; so it should be &nbsp; not &nbsp.